# Proving $\mathcal{D}$-class of semigroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

> #### Theorem 2.17
>
> *If $a$ and $b$ are elements of a semigroup $S$, then $ab\in R_a\cap L_b$ if and only if $R_b\cap L_a$ contains an idempotent. If this is the case, then
>   $$aH_b = H_a b = H_a H_b = H_{ab} = R_a \cap L_b.$$*
>
> #### Lemma 8.35
>
> *Let $S$ be an inverse semigroup and let $e$ be any idempotent of $S$. Then
>
>   (i) $L_e R_e = D_e$;
>   (ii) let $l,l_1 \in L_e$ and $r,r_1\in R_e$; then $lr = l_1 r_1$ if and only if there exists $u\in H_e$ such that $lu=l_1$ and $ur_1 = r$.*
>
> #### Proof
>
> (i) Let $a\in D_e$ and choose $b\in R_e\cap L_a$ and $c\in R_a \cap L_e$. Then, by Theorem 2.17, $H_c b = H_a$ ($H_x$ denotes the $\mathscr H$-class containing $x$). Thus $a\in H_c b \subseteq L_e b \subseteq L_e R_e$. This shows that $D_e \subseteq L_e R_e$. The converse containment holds by Theorem 2.4. Thus $L_e R_e = D_e$.

The problem is in Lemma 8.35, how can I choose $b$ and $c$. And $b$ and $c$ should be idempotent?

I know that if $a \in D_{e}$, then there exist $x,y \in S^{1}$ such that
$x \in R_{e} \cap L_{a}$ and $y \in R_{a} \cap L_{e}$. Thank you.

Comment: What do $R_a$, $L_a$, $H_a$, and $D_a$ mean? $L_a$ and $R_a$ look like the left- and right- subsemigroups generated by $a$, but I can't tell anything about the others.

Comment: @William They are the [Green's equivalence classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations) containing $a$. For example, $b\in \mathcal{R}_a$ means that there exists $x\in S$ such that $ax=b$ (they are *right related*).

Answer (score 1):

$b$ an $c$ are choosen arbitrary, but $R_b=R_e, L_c=L_e$. Hence $R_b\cap L_c$ contains $e$, and we can apply Theorem 2.17.

Comment: Thank you so much. If you mind asking you a question? I know that a semigroup $S$ is bisimple if $S$ contains a single $\mathcal{D}$-class or $\mathcal{D} = S \times S$. But when we prove it, what is the concept of proof. Example is this [link](http://books.google.co.th/books?id=Z8B9RWus3XMC&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=D+subsemigroup+bisimple&source=bl&ots=folN2uUHDb&sig=y7EY6577U_Hs4ygZk_5CoRsLpWA&hl=th&sa=X&ei=_FYJUobkDonxiAeX3oCgCg&ved=0CE4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=D%20subsemigroup%20bisimple&f=false), LEMMA 8.38.

Comment: What exactly do not you understand in Lemma $8.38$?